Install an InstallShield package in powershell using powershell remoting
I've noticed in a powershell remote session a couple of installers that I want to install silently aren't performing their installation. I would like to understand if there's a logical explanation to what is happening.
I have a handfull of (windows-) machines that I need to adminstrate remotely. One of a common element is installating software packages. Some of the packages are based on install shield (exe + cab files). I have recorded an instruction file, and playing back the instruction file is working when run directly on the workstation.
When I run the commands through powershell remoting session the (install shield) log file states there were no errors. However the software does not actually get installed. When I run the same commands in psexec terminal the software installs without problems.
I have encountered one element in powershell remoting that I suspect could be relevant, from an powershell remoting session it seems I am unable run commands that require being run under different credentionals (impersonation?). For example Start-Process with credentionals always failed, likewise runas /user:... failed. I believe what could be happening is that install shield requires running some elements as a different (system-)user and runs into same problem internally.
That being said, I would like to know what is happening and if there's a solution to this problem. It seems to me that powershell remoting is very unreliable if it prevents installing thirdparty software packages.

Just to clarify:
Software based on msi packages that I can execute directly through msiexec install without problems. It's specific to InstallShield based 'setup.exe', unfortunately I haven't had any luck unpacking the software to another format but I'd prefer solution for the underlying problem so when I perform ad-hoc commands I can rely on their output.

What does the PowerShell command(s) look like when you install it locally and interactively, and are there are UI prompts via that interactive PS method you must click to proceed? Have you tried Invoke-Command -ComputerName <machinexyz> -ScriptBlock {<Install Command(s) ABC;> } -Credential (Get-Credential) and wrapping Start-Process, etc. within the scriptblock that way? Remote PS is not interactive and can have double-hop or delegation issues that need workaround for installing software. I assume the exe and the output location are local file system and nothing network/UNC, correct?

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle the software comes from unc but is copied over locally, the commands are the same E:\SOFTWARE\setup.exe /s /SMS /f1"E:\data\response.iss" /f2"E:\data\install.log" /a /verbose /v"/qn /l*vx E:\data\msi.log"
There are no interactive elements to the setup to my knowledge, and as stated Start-Process with seperate credentionals doesn't work from ScriptBlock.

Assuming E:\SOFTWARE\setup.exe and E:\data\response.iss exist on the remote machine executing the commands from it's OS perspective, you tried the command with this syntax? Invoke-Command -ComputerName MachineXYZ -ScriptBlock {Start-Process -FilePath "E:\SOFTWARE\setup.exe" -ArgumentList '/s /SMS /f1"E:\data\response.iss" /f2"E:\data\install.log" /a /verbose /v"/qn /l*vx E:\data\msi.log"'} -Credential (Get-Credential) correct?

Yes that's correct. I generally avoid redunant elements i.e. Start-Process but I have tried that variation as well.  The Start-Process allowed me to try elements like -Credential, -LoadUserProfile, -UseNewEnvironment in which case it always fails.
Invoke-Command $hostName -Credential $cred -Scriptblock { E:\SOFTWARE\setup.exe /s /SMS /f1"E:\data\response.iss" /f2"E:\data\install.log" /a /verbose /v"/qn /l*vx E:\data\msi.log" }
